# How to get ICCID number from IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am Trying to get the ICCID from Iphone. can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean via programming method? You can't.

Comment: Yes i am trying to fetch through programming method. Tanks for your reply.

Comment: Can u please help me to identify the sim. with any serial number. In android we can able to find the sim using IMSI like wise is there any option to find it.

Comment: To find out IMSI, you have to be jailbroken first. No official way to do so. Why do you want to find out IMSI ?

Comment: I am doing some sort of payment module so i need to find the user so i need to find the user/sim.

Comment: Can you use MAC address ? It is unique for all mobile devices (all network devices actually).

Comment: No actually i tried with but that is of no use in my case. I need any information regarding the sim, and that must be unique for each sim.

Comment: You may require telecommunication company's API. In my project, I use local telecommunication company's API to identify the information of the user, by its data IP & mobile number.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to get telecommunication company's API  and get back to you.